# SQL-Select statement with multiple columns , with no result

Tags: sql, select, db2

I need to join two select statements in DB2 in the following way:
If the first select returns no rows, then execute the second select.
If the first select returns rows, then do not executes the second select.
I need it in select statement please, not a function or procedure.
both select from diff tables. and both selects have multiple columns.

```
Select c1,c2 from table1

Select v1,v2 from table2
```

I tried all kind of joins and Case and Not exists keyword...but no luck.
any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT c1,c2 FROM table1)
    SELECT c1,c2 FROM table1
ELSE
    SELECT v1,v2 FROM table2
```

Another approach would be:

```
SELECT c1, c2 FROM table1 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT c1, c2 FROM table1)
UNION ALL
SELECT v1, v2 FROM table2 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT c1, c2 FROM table1)
```

Comment: Thank you Michal, This doesn't help, because I need the whole thing inside a select statement...  something like this SELECT CASE WHEN (Select c1,c2 from table1) IS NULL THEN (Select v1,v2 from table2) ELSE (Select c1,c2 from table1)

Comment: The problem with UNION ALL , I will end up with two rows when both select statements are true. I don't want to execute the second select if the first select returns data.

Comment: Michal, Thank you so much it worked...I'm sorry I didn't see the exists in your Union All statements...

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
Declare @Count int
select @Count = Count(*) FROM table1
if @Count > 0
begin
SELECT c1,c2 FROM table1
end
else if @Count = 0
begin
SELECT v1,v2 FROM table2
end
```